# How to calculate using trigger?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE table_test_trigger (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  a INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  b INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  c INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON table_test_trigger
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.c = NEW.a + NEW.b;
END
$$
```

I've tried this code.

**Error:**

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'%' */
    TRIGGER `trigger1` BEFORE INSERT ON `table_test_trigger` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        SET NEW.c = NEW.a + NEW.b;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine ..there is no error in the trigger or table. Data will be inserted peacefully..!**May be you have given some extra spaces in between while trying**...Just check out that

Other than that there is no error it is fine...! (I tried it in my machine It worked fine..!)

Do one thing just neatly take it up into a notepad remove all extra spaces or character if any you see, then paste it into the terminal, It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The script is correct. It is possible that your MySQL client does not support delimiters. Your trigger has only one statement, so you can omit BEGIN-END clause and DELIMITER command.

```
CREATE TABLE table_test_trigger (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  a INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  b INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  c INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON table_test_trigger
  FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.c = NEW.a + NEW.b;
```